# Number forwarding Cisco CallManager Express

Tags: cisco

I would like to set up number forwarding on Cisco CallManager so that when, for example, "888" is dialled, the call is forwarded to "00912345678".

In my scheme the leading zero is for an external call, "09" is the outside area code, and "12345678" is the subscriber number.

This can easily be done as follows (this was tested and it works):

```
ephone-dn  123
  number 888
  call-forward all 00912345678
```

Now, I also assumed that I could use translation rules to get the same forwarding result (I am new to CallManager). I have experimented with many variations on the following idea, but I could not get it to work:

```
voice translation-rule 888
  rule 1 /^888$/ /00912345678/


voice translation-profile PIZZA
  translate calling 888


voice-port 0/1/0:15
  ...
  translation-profile outgoing PIZZA
  ...


dial-peer voice 1 pots
  ...
  port 0/1/0:15
  ...
```

My questions are:

1. Can translation rules be used to create dialing shortcuts/translations?
2. Why isn't the above working?